BMI Calculator Not Giving Expected Result (Python)
I am not getting the expected outcome from my BMI Calculator code (in Python). The only visible output is just the first input value instead of the product of a BMI calculation. Pycharm is not flagging any errors with the code but when I run the code it needs to be terminated manually instead of coming to a natural conclusion.
This is my code:
height = float (input (1.8))
weight = float (input (150))

bmi = weight / height **2
bmi2 = int (bmi)
print(bmi2)


I was expecting an output of 46 (BMI = weight divided by the height squared) but instead it just shows 1.8 in the console until the run is terminated manually.

I guess you missunderstand the input command. It promts the user to input something into the console. Type 1.8 then press enter and then 150 and press enter and the console will show the expected 46!

Take a look at this

You might want to have a look at the documentation: input

Thank you all for replying. It is appreciated.

You're using input incorrectly.
The input function uses the argument it's given as a prompt to the user and then blocks and waits for their input from the standard input.
In other words, if you want to take user input, you should probably have more meaningful prompts than 80 and 150, e.g.:
height = float(input('Please enter your height: '))
weight = float(input('Please enter your weitht: '))

If you don't want to take user input but just the BMI of someone with a height  of 1.8 and a weight of 150, don't call input:
height = 1.8
weight = 150

FWIW, for these values, your program indeed calculates 46 correctly.

Thank you for your reply. This was extremely helpful and it is now running correctly.

This is because the '1.8' in the console is actually a prompt for the input function. If you just want to use the raw value '1.8' as soon as the script runs, remove the use of the input function.
To read more about the input function, read the Python docs for built-in functions.
